# A practically irrelevant just mildly interesting algorithm and how do I get the logic to work?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, math, logic, jagged-arrays

I was in the shower yesterday, and an idea hit me. It's a mathematical pattern or set of rules to find a list of integers.

The practical application of this pattern or whatever you could call it is up to the super mathematicians, I just wanted to see if I could make a program that could find it.

At the moment I'm using VB.net as it's what I HAVE to use for college right now, but im open to C++ as well.

So, the rules of this pattern are:

You get an Integer as your "factor", and multiply it by itself as many times as you like. This creates a list of numbers that you use as namespaces or what I'd call "containers".

If the factor was say, 2, the list would look like this - 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 etc. (excluding the base factor).

Now under each item of the list you place all integers that could fit inside it. If the number of the container is 8 for example, every number from 1 to 7 would be listed.

However the rules go further than that.

A number inside the container cannot be listed if;

- it's = 1 or 2
- it's = any number in the container before
- it's = the factor before
- or is divisible by any number in the container before.

For example

```
[4]-[8]-[16]-[32]
 3   7   13   31
     5   12   29
         11   26
         9    25
         6    23
         4    19
         3    17
              14
              10
              7
              5
```

As you can see the numbers you get are always different. So I was working on a form in VS 2015, that allowed you to enter the factor, and the number of iterations (how long the list went) in the list.

The issue is, as you might of guessed by the fact that I'm actually doing this in the first place, is that my logic isn't all that great. As a programer I am a begginer, and as a logical thinker I am not the best.

See below what I've tried out so far. It's just what was in between the button sub:

```
    Dim iteration As Integer = EtrIterationCount.Text
    Dim factor As Integer = EtrNumericFactor.Text
    Dim Container()() As Integer = New Integer(iteration)() {}
    ReDim Container(iteration)(1)
    Dim Contents() As Integer = New Integer() {}

    Dim Base As Integer = factor


    For X = 1 To iteration - 1

        Container(X)(1) = New Integer()
        Base = Base * factor
        Container(X)(0) = Base

    Next


    Container(0)(0) = factor


    For X = 0 To iteration - 1
        Dim Test As Integer = Container(X)(0)
        Dim Num = Test


        For Num = Num To 0 Step -1

            If X = 0 Then
                For W = Num To 0 Step -1
                    If Not Test = 1 Then
                        Contents(W) = Test
                    End If
                Next
                Array.ConstrainedCopy(Contents, Contents.Length, Container, Container(X)(1), Contents.Length)

            ElseIf X >= 1 Then

                For W = Num To 0 Step -1
                    For J = 0 To Contents.Length - 1

                        If Not Contents(J) Mod Container(X - 1)(1) = 0 Then
                            If Not Test = 1 And Test = Container(X)(0) And Contents.Contains(Test) Then
                                Contents(W) = Test

                            End If

                        End If

                    Next

                Next

                Array.ConstrainedCopy(Contents, Contents.Length, Container, Container(X)(1), Contents.Length)

            End If

            Test = Test - 1

            MsgBox(Container(X)(1))

        Next

    Next
```

What I have basically tried to do, is something I've not done before, and create a jagged/nested array, the first array acting as the container listing all the iterations and its first row containing the factored numbers, the second row containing the array with the list of values.

It was suggested by a first that I use Vectors, or a class of vectors to sort out this problem, but I haven't got the foggiest how to do that.

If anything I would like this to be practice on how to deal with arrays and maybe teach me some logic that I'm missing.

Comment: Your second rule is covered by the fourth rule; the former would only be worth implementing in code if the latter was significantly more expensive to check.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to do this, many of them better than what I came up with, but a [`Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will suffice to hold the data:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Console.Write("Factor: ")
        Dim factor = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.Write("Iterations: ")
        Dim iters = CInt(Console.ReadLine())

        Dim result As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))

        Dim thisSection = factor
        Dim prevSection = 0

        For i = 2 To iters + 1
            thisSection = thisSection * factor
            result.Add(thisSection, New List(Of Integer))

            For j = 3 To thisSection - 1

                Dim isDivisible = False

                If prevSection > 0 Then
                    If j Mod prevSection = 0 Then
                        isDivisible = True
                    End If

                    If Not isDivisible Then
                        For Each n In result(prevSection)
                            If j Mod n = 0 Then
                                isDivisible = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                End If

                If Not isDivisible Then
                    result(thisSection).Add(j)
                End If

            Next

            prevSection = thisSection

        Next

        For Each de In result
            Console.WriteLine("[" & de.Key.ToString() & "] " & String.Join(", ", de.Value.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x)))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Sample output:

> Factor: 2
>   Iterations: 4
>   [4] 3
>   [8] 7, 5
>   [16] 13, 12, 11, 9, 6, 4, 3
>   [32] 31, 29, 25, 23, 19, 17, 14, 10, 7, 5

A List is pretty much like an array, but you can add to it without knowing the number of entries in advance (it increases its capacity automatically).

The variable names I used could probably be more descriptive.

Incidentally, in your example you have 26 in the [32] column, but 13 (=26/2) is in the [16] column.

Comment: Thats for the error spot, thats what i get for just waking up and doing it with a pencil by hand.... 

I was thinking of a list, but didn't know it could go beyond a single dimension. Or if it did, i didn't know how to structure it.

Comment: Ok checked it, it works, just about, but sort of explodes for anything more than 10 iterations :D i think i need a supercomputer.

Comment: It appears that the ratio of the quantity of numbers generated for a "factor" of 2 tends to e (2.78128...) and 2^0.5 (1.4142...) alternately ([524288] gives 90182 numbers, [1048576] 243707, [2097152] 341314). However, even parallelising the generation of the numbers will not get you far as the time taken increases at a very fast rate with the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Also check this out. It uses the Chain pattern. More easy to add new rule.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim results As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))

        Dim initialValue As Integer = 2
        Dim multiplier As Integer = 4

        For i As Integer = 2 To multiplier + 1
            results.Add(Convert.ToInt32(initialValue ^ i), New List(Of Integer))
        Next

        For dictionaryIndex As Integer = 0 To results.Count - 1
            Dim currentFactor As Integer = results.Keys(dictionaryIndex)

            For testValue As Integer = 1 To currentFactor - 1
                Dim chain As New ChainOfRules()
                chain.AddRule(New NotInValuesRule(testValue, 1, 2))

                If (dictionaryIndex > 0) Then
                    Dim previousFactor As Integer = results.Keys(dictionaryIndex - 1)
                    chain.AddRule(New NotInValuesRule(testValue, results(previousFactor).ToArray))
                    chain.AddRule(New NotInValuesRule(testValue, previousFactor))
                    chain.AddRule(New NotDivisibleListRule(testValue, results(previousFactor).ToArray))
                End If

                If (chain.Process) Then
                    results(currentFactor).Add(testValue)
                End If
            Next
        Next

        For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, List(Of Integer)) In results
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Factor: {0}", pair.Key)
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------")
            For Each i As Integer In pair.Value
                Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", i)
            Next
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub





    ' Rules

    Public Interface IRule
        Function Apply() As Boolean
    End Interface


    Public Class NotInValuesRule
        Implements IRule

        Private Property Value As Integer
        Private Property ValuesList As List(Of Integer)

        Public Sub New(value As Integer, ParamArray valuesList As Integer())
            Me.Value = value
            Me.ValuesList = valuesList.ToList()
        End Sub

        Public Function Apply() As Boolean Implements IRule.Apply
            Return Not ValuesList.Contains(Value)
        End Function
    End Class


    Public Class NotDivisibleListRule
        Implements IRule

        Private Property Value As Integer
        Private Property ValuesList As List(Of Integer)

        Public Sub New(value As Integer, ParamArray valuesList As Integer())
            Me.Value = value
            Me.ValuesList = valuesList.ToList
        End Sub

        Public Function Apply() As Boolean Implements IRule.Apply
            Dim result As Boolean = True

            For Each previousValue As Integer In ValuesList
                result = result And (Value Mod previousValue <> 0)
            Next

            Return result
        End Function
    End Class


    Public Class ChainOfRules
        Private Property Rules As New List(Of IRule)

        Public Sub AddRule(rule As IRule)
            Rules.Add(rule)
        End Sub

        Public Function Process() As Boolean
            Dim result As Boolean = True

            For Each Rule As IRule In Rules
                result = result And Rule.Apply()
            Next

            Return result
        End Function
    End Class

End Module
```